# Auto restart after updates option is greyed out in Windows 10

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-v1709

My Windows 10 auto restart after updates option is greyed out, and I can't turn it on or off. I clicked on the on/off button to turn on the option but it doesn't work.

I have `Windows 10 Home 1709 OS Build 16299.309 64-bit`

Answer (score 0):

The [restart policy can be managed in the Registry.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart) To enable auto-restart:

- Press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key.
- Type `regedit` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (or click *Yes*) in the UAC dialog.
- In *Regedit*, in the location bar at top, enter (or copy-and-paste from here) 
  `HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU`
   and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- On the right should be the key `NoAutoRebootWithLoggedOnUsers`. Double-click on it and change its value to 0 (*zero*).

Note that there are other keys, such as `AlwaysAutoRebootAtScheduledTime` and `AlwaysAutoRebootAtScheduledTimeMinutes`, that can also influence automatic rebooting. See [Manage device restarts after updates](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/update/waas-restart) for more information.